# What does this kernel panic means?

Tags: kernel, wubi

I am using ZenBook ASUS and after trying to install virtual box from ubuntu software center on ubuntu 11.10 unity, I faced with kernel panic and from that time from time to time I am facing with the same error! I used Wubi and have dual boot with Windows Home Premium with Ubuntu 11.10! I could also involve screen shots in case necessary!
PS: I did reinstall Ubuntu once again and now this time it happened while downloading a codec:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wwdjeo&s=5

I should say I am installing ubuntu via Wubi! Any solution?

Comment: Try to improve your question by using the edit button instead of adding information to the comments.

Comment: A screen-shot or a copy of the kernel panic test will be helpful.

Comment: Screen shot now is in the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a long comment than an answer.

You have an *scheduling while atomic* bug, this always means that there is a bug in some driver that you are using. It means that some code that was supposed to be atomic (it shouldn't be interrupted) has called the scheduler.

I can't see from the screenshot what driver is causing the problem.

As some kind of workaround you can try the new [12.04 beta](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/), maybe the bug is resolved in it. You can find the Wubi installer inside the ISO. But be careful, it is a beta and there is no guaranty that it will solve your bug.

Comment: can it be related to Ethernet driver for asus zenbook bundle? since u should download n install this driver manually. Do you recommend to move to another ditribution maybe?

Comment: Sure, it could be, try to remove it. I recommend that you try a newer kernel, changing distros with the same kernel are not likely to change anything.

Comment: If the problem is the Ethernet driver, you should try a distro with a kernel version >= 3.2. Precise (Ubuntu 12.04) does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically the problem was that when you are using ASUS Zenbook ethernet driver and then you are installing virtualbox, since virtualbox tries to map that driver to its configuration, it leads to a kernel panic for kernel 3.0 ubuntu. I did not upgrade the kernel however I reinstalled Ubuntu and did not install ethernet driver and it is working just fine. I installed VirtualBox and it is up and running, meaning that it is a bug from ASUS Driver somehow.